# Tinymce bug text "-webkit-standard" shows in safari in font dropdown

Tags: angular, tinymce

Tinymce bug  text "-webkit-standard" shows in safari in font dropdown. Look in added pic - there are one in chrome (-webkit-standard) and another on in safari.
Does anybody forced such issue?
[image]

[image]

In DOM Safari added span.
[image]

Answer (score 0):

Fixed by add:

```
    if (BrowserDetection.isSafari()) {
      event.target.editorCommands.execCommand("fontName", false, "Times");
    }
```